# "update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for libvirtd"

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to install and configure KVM in my ubuntu machine. Providing below given code i am getting error.

Command: update-rc.d libvirtd enable

error  : "update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for libvirtd"

I have checked the script named 'libvirt-bin' related to this command under '/etc/init.d' and it has appropriate header as shown below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Init script for libvirtd
#
# (c) 2007 Guido Guenther <agx@sigxcpu.org>
# based on the skeletons that comes with dh_make
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          libvirtd libvirt-bin
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog virtlogd
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog virtlogd
# Should-Start:      avahi-daemon cgconfig
# Should-Stop:       avahi-daemon cgconfig
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: libvirt management daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

Now i am not able to solve this LSB script error.

My OS details:
Linux version 4.15.0-112-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-021) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #113~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 04:37:08 UTC 2020

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Note:
To install KVM, i am following steps from the link "https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-kvm-ubuntu-18-04-server/"

*I can not change the version of my OS as this is office system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the doc you linked this is in the section "In case libvirtd service is not started and enabled" which should not be the case. So you should not need this command anyway. But if it is disabled after install please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+filebug) with steps to recreate so I can sort it out.

And even if your service isn't running, the update-rc is outdated, probably a copy forward from an old howto. Even if it would not be enabled due to systemd in Xenial and later the command to enable it would be like:

```
systemctl enable libvirt-bin.service
```

And while I think people should adopt to the new tools, in case you insist on using update-rc.d, then the problem is that `libvirtd` isn't the right name - the following would have worked (but eventually does the same as the more modern command above):

```
update-rc.d libvirt-bin enable
```

Answer (score 0):

use this and run in terminal. this solved my problem

```
systemctl start libvirtd
```